# Search through Table Cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, loops

I have a table which is hidden which contains 1272 rows and within it 3 columns with a

1. Store Name
2. Postcode
3. Button

The script is meant to search for all `td` cells for either a store name or a postcode and is not  returning the desired results.

This is a link to the [search](http://www.thosedigitalthoughts.com/hysai/)

Advice appreciated

```
$("#searchterm").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $.trim($(this).val().toLowerCase());


    $("table#participating_stores tr:gt(0)").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {
            $row = $(this);
            
            var $tdElement = $row.find("td");
            var id = $.trim($tdElement.text().toLowerCase()) 

            var matchedIndex = id.indexOf(value);
            
            if (matchedIndex != 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                //highlight matching text, passing element and matched text
      
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There are a few matters: 1. The `find('td')` gets all three cells of a row, but ... 2. Then the next `trim()` to `id` gets the text from all 3 of those cells, and it looks something like this: `iga zuccoli832go to survey`. 3. I would think the `matchedIndex` should check for `== -1` (-1 implies _not found_) to hide the row(s), not 0? ... Use the browser's debugger to set breakpoints and step through the javascript code to follow the handling.

Comment: Thanks Paul that  was very helpful , I wasnt sure what the -1 meant

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.  I've made this runnable snippet which hopefully makes things more clear for you and anyone else trying to think about this problem.

```js
$("#searchterm").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  $("table tr:not(:first)").show().filter(function(index) {
      return $(this).find("td").text().indexOf(value) == -1;
  }).hide();
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
}

table th{
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><th>Postal Code</th><th>Store Name</th></tr>
    <tr><td>12345</td><td>store name</td></tr>
    <tr><td>99999</td><td>another store name</td></tr>
    <tr><td>54321</td><td>yet another name</td></tr>
    <tr><td>34343</td><td>4th name</td></tr>
    <tr><td>87898</td><td>fifth name</td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="searchterm" placeholder="search"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it is much faster and shorter. I modified it here so the table is shown and  hidden and set a timer for an empty string which mostly works

[here](http://www.thosedigitalthoughts.com/hysai/)